# Time Series Visualization

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

Does anyone know how I could create a graph like this one to visualize time series of anual temperature for different years in R?
[image]

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard surface plot. Just look for "*plot a surface over the an x-y plane*".

Such plots can be created with base R but they are many other packages (e.g. `rgl`, `ggplot`, etc.) that offer similar (and more sophisticated) functionality. Here is a quick proof-of-concept with base-R:

```
set.seed(14)
x <- seq(1772, 2017, by = 10)
y <- seq(-2, 5, length = length(x))
z <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) sin(b)) + runif(n=length(x)^2, max=0.3)
persp(x, y, z, phi=10, theta=-50)
```

[image]

Comment: Characterizing this as a "surface plot" misses the characteristic feature that it appears to interpolate smoothly in just one direction.  It is, in effect, a pseudo-3D stack of curves. Another special aspect is that each curve is a (univariate) *histogram:* thus, each $y$ cross-section integrates to unity.

Comment: I disagree. Characterising it as not a surface plot complicates its implementation in terms of plotting. Whether or not this is the density or not, or smoothed or not, is immaterial to the plotting and mostly complicates the solution. (I did think of normalising each trajectoriy to integrate to 1 but the realised it just added a potentially redundant layer of functionality.)

Comment: On the contrary, once you recognize the nature of this plot, it allows for a *simpler* algorithm (one of the earliest known for such pseudo 3D plots).  More importantly, the nature of the surface and of the interpolation are important and would likely not be rendered accurately by an arbitrary interpolator.

Comment: I do not think that the interpolation as a part of the plotting implementation. "*it allows for a simpler algorithm (one of the earliest known for such pseudo 3D plots)*". OK, let's see it in R (or your language of choice). :) I might learn something new (from you) (*again*).

Comment: Plotting is tantamount to interpolation. The method illustrated in the question appears related to one of the first 3D methods developed because it didn't need clever ways to remove hidden features: you simply draw the cross-sections back to front, letting each new one occlude the others. You can probably find good examples and descriptions in any graphics textbook published before c. 1985. It looks like `persp` triangulates the data, which works here when all cross-sections are evenly sampled; if you tried to apply almost any other method of interpolation, this plot will look very different.

Comment: I think now we are venturing into what could have happened behind the question. If the data weren't equisampled, if the data needed interpolation, if it had "hidden features" we had to remove. Ehh... OK, if my interpolator had infinite support it would be an extrapolator. Your point about "*simply draw the cross-sections back to front*" is pretty much my point too here. Just use a simple surface plotting routine and move forward with it.